# Comment / Note in a JFree Chart

Tags: charts, jfreechart, comments

I am looking for a way to insert a specific comment / note in an image created by JFree Chart. The note can be anywhere on the image (png), above or below the chart.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add text, [`addSubtitle()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html#addSubtitle%28org.jfree.chart.title.Title%29) is a common approach, and [`TextTitle`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/title/TextTitle.html) is a convenient implementation of the `Title` interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you  want to create a comment or not on Image itself... you can do this with the use of `Marker`.
If you want something below the image/graph use the `LegendItemCollection`.